# Is it OK to use the maps.google.cn API outside of China?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps is available in China per their documentation:

> The Google Maps APIs are served within China from the domain
>   maps.google.cn. This domain does not support https. When making
>   requests to the Google Maps APIs from China, please replace
>   https://maps.googleapis.com with http://maps.google.cn.

I have tested this outside China without any issues, however I can't find any documentation that prohibit developers from using http://maps.google.cn outside of china. Does anyone knows about any restrictions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I use Google Maps API in China?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946982/how-should-i-use-google-maps-api-in-china)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is already stated in that description. The "https://maps.googleapis.com" or simply **"https"** is not supported in the China. That is why you need to use **"http"** and not **"https"**. There is no problem with that outside of China because we can still access that http://maps.google.cn. The only issue is http is not a secured and the data is not encrypted, and it can be intercepted by third parties to gather data being passed between the two systems.

So if you are not in China, it is better to use the https://maps.googleapis.com. The http://maps.google.cn is only for the people who wants to use Google Map that is live in China.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks @KENdi, I assumed as much but I just don't know the restrictions of using google.cn outside of china. Do we get the same number of allocated requests? Would we get flagged if we use the service for a long periods of time outside of cn? Is it also mirrored to the Google's CDN outside of cn?

Comment: Do we get the same number of allocated requests? Yes, I think it is the same. Would we get flagged if we use the service for a long periods of time outside of cn? No, it is not stated in the document that we should not use it even though we are not in the China region.

Comment: This appears to work for some things, but not for the Autocomplete API. From my tests (outside of China, which may not be accurate) the API is still calling `https://maps.googleapis.com` even though I have referenced `maps.google.cn` in the `<script>` tag.